# Как пофиксить ошибку error: expected '{' before '*' token

Tags: c

Пытаюсь запустить следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct g_list {
char item[100];
char unit[3];
float amount;
};

void get_command(struct *new_list){//внутри функции указатель к структуре списка покупок
    int command;
    printf("create new list: 1 \n");
    printf("create add item to list: 2 \n");
    printf("print the list: 3 \n");
    printf("erase the list: 4 \n");
    printf("remove item from the list: 5 \n");
    scanf("%d",command);
    switch (command){
        case 1: crate_new_list();
        case 2: add_item(*new_list);
        case 3: print_the_list(*new_list);
        case 4: erase_the_list(*new_list);
        case 5: remove_item_from_list(*new_list);
        default: // если ввел не правильную команду, надо еще раз попробовать ввести команду
        printf("Please enter the correct command");
        get_command();
    }
}

void create_new_list(){// тут создаем новый лист покупок
    struct g_list new_list[]; // создаем новую структуру покупок и пихаем его в массив
    get_command(&new_list); // передаем адрес нового списка покупок для выбора команды
}

void add_item(*new_list){// тут создаем новый лист покупок
    size = sizeof(*new_list); // Получаем список листа покупок или список массива
    new_item = *new_list[size+1]; //добавляем новую запись в массиве
    scanf("%s%s%d",new_item.item,new_item.unit,new_item.amount); //выводим в экране чтобы прочитали
    get_command(&new_list); // передаем адрес нового списка покупок для выбора команды
}

void print_the_list(*new_list){// тут создаем новый лист покупок
    printf("Item    Unit    Amount");
    size = sizeof(*new_list); // Получаем размер списка покупок
    for (int i=0;i<=size;i++){//пробегаемся по каждому из них
        struct item = *new_list[i]; //чтобы было удобно выводить, записываем его в переменную структуру
        printf("%s, %s, %d",item.item,item.unit,item.amount); // выводим на экран
    }
}


void erase_the_list(*list){// 
    *list= struct g_list new_list[]; //просто создаем новый массив из структуры.
}

int main(void) {
    get_command();
    int command;
    scanf("%d",command);
    printf("%d",command);
    return 0;
}
```

Получаю следующие ошибки:

```
main.c:10:25: error: expected '{' before '*' token
 void get_command(struct *new_list){//внутри функции указатель к структуре списка покупок
                         ^
main.c: In function 'get_command':
main.c:17:13: error: 'command' undeclared (first use in this function)
  scanf("%d",command);
             ^
main.c:17:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:19:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'crate_new_list' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   case 1: crate_new_list();
           ^
main.c:20:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'add_item' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   case 2: add_item(*new_list);
           ^
main.c:21:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'print_the_list' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   case 3: print_the_list(*new_list);
           ^
main.c:22:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'erase_the_list' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   case 4: erase_the_list(*new_list);
           ^
main.c:23:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'remove_item_from_list' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   case 5: remove_item_from_list(*new_list);
           ^
main.c:26:3: error: too few arguments to function 'get_command'
   get_command();
   ^
main.c:10:6: note: declared here
 void get_command(struct *new_list){//внутри функции указатель к структуре списка покупок
      ^
main.c: In function 'create_new_list':
main.c:31:16: error: array size missing in 'new_list'
  struct g_list new_list[]; // создаем новую структуру покупок и пихаем его в массив
                ^
main.c:32:14: warning: passing argument 1 of 'get_command' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  get_command(&new_list); // передаем адрес нового списка покупок для выбора команды
              ^
main.c:10:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'struct g_list (*)[1]'
 void get_command(struct *new_list){//внутри функции указатель к структуре списка покупок
      ^
main.c: At top level:
main.c:35:15: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
 void add_item(*new_list){// тут создаем новый лист покупок
               ^
main.c:42:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
 void print_the_list(*new_list){// тут создаем новый лист покупок
                     ^
main.c:52:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
 void erase_the_list(*list){// 
                     ^
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:57:2: error: too few arguments to function 'get_command'
  get_command();
  ^
main.c:10:6: note: declared here
 void get_command(struct *new_list){//внутри функции указатель к структуре списка покупок
      ^
main.c:59:8: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%d",command);
        ^
main.c:59:2: warning: ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  scanf("%d",command);
  ^
```

Насколько я понимаю, всё дело в первой ошибке, из-за этого валится всё остальное, но как её пофиксить? Спасибо.

Comment: `void get_command(struct *new_list)` — у вас некорректное объявление. `struct` есть, а вот имени структуры нет.

Comment: Код битком набит синтаксическими ошибками при объявлении параметров функций. Причем ошибки разные. Что такое `void add_item(*new_list)`? Также, почему вы решили, что `sizeof` будет давать вам некий "размер списка покупок"?

Comment: Вам лучше начать с более простых задачек - у вас уж слишком много простейших ошибок...

Comment: Тут проще перечислить, в каких строках нет ошибок, чем в каких они есть. Для начала вам нужно разобраться, что такое строгая типизация и указатели, а потом уже начинать писать что-то с использованием списков.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь:

```
void get_command(struct *new_list) { ...
```

надо также указать имя структуры:

```
void get_command(struct g_list *new_list) { ...
```

Компилируйте код небольшими частями, быстрей диагностицируете дальнейшие ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Дак читайте ошибки которые вам пишет компилятор. Черным по белому написано же.

`void get_command(struct *new_list)` - неправильное объявление функции. Почему в функции  `scanf ();` забыли взятие адреса добавить?  Почему при использовании `switch` между кейсами не ставите `break;`, у вас же все кейсы так по порядку и пройдут. Почему в функцию `get_command ();` не передаёте должное количество аргументов? Дальше смотреть не стал, полная белиберда. Простейшие ошибки на ровном месте. Думаю это слишком сложный код для вас, пока начните с чего нибудь полегче.